# Could not find or load main (Ubuntu Java)

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, jar

I use in Windows cmd:

> java -cp "E:\myproject\backend\build\WEB-INF\lib\backend.jar;E:\myproject\backend\libs*" com.droid.myproject.backend.BackendServer

but after put next string in Ubuntu terminal, I get

> java -cp "/home/droid/andro/staging1/myproject/backend/build/WEB-INF/lib/backend.jar;/home/droid/andro/staging1/myproject/backend/libs/*" com.droid.myproject.backend.BackendServer
>
> **Error: Could not find or load main class com.droid.myproject.backend.BackendServer**

What is my fault?

Comment: remove the quotes from classpath and use the ":"  as seperator

Comment: I have added the sollution as answer. Feel free to upvote or accept this as it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

remove the quotes from classpath and use the ":" as seperator